# What is BPO's and Mr. Whispers' motivation?

Tags: character-motivation, sense8

I just finished watching the first season of Sense 8, and one major part of the plot just didn't add up for me: The motivation of the antagonists (BPO and Mr. Whispers).

Spoilers Ahead:

> BPO and Mr. Whispers want to find, capture and neutralize (by killing or lobotomizing) each of the sense8's. Now BPO is a multi-government run organization, and it is stated in the show that they fear the sense8's. But Mr. Whispers is a sense8 himself. Not only that, but he appears to be the head of BPO. Why would an organization that fears sense8's, not only knowingly employ a sense8, but allow him to run the organization? Why would Mr. Whispers (a powerful sense8), want to find, capture, and neutralize other sense8's?

Answer (score 5):

I've just rewatched the season and there is no motivation (yet).

Season 1 was very obviously all about character development and setting up events for upcoming seasons. So, other than the default "nefarious organization wants to kill everything" motive, I suspect that'll be a focus of coming seasons.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I missed something or not, but I guess this confirms I didn't miss an explanation... Though it doesn't really answer the question. It sounds like this will be one of those "There is no answer right now" questions. Hopefully this will get explained later; as of right now I see it as a major plot hole since it doesn't make sense why the antagonists are doing what they are doing.

Comment: I totally agree

Comment: I don't think the nefarious organization is out to kill, only lobotomize, which they may not have down pat. For instance in episode 8, Whispers uses the vegetable Niles Bolger as a tool. If he can get as many sensates in that state as possible he has bodies all over that he can get into and use. For what purpose, though, that's yet to be given.

Answer (score 0):

The fans don't know what's going to happen until the cluster knows because we watch them grow and learn as they do - that's how the writers want it to be.